# Android Studio: Unresolved reference: box_three_text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I try to make an application to practice Layout in Android, but I get an error:

> Unresolved reference: box_three_text

See screenshot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3uGt.jpg

Why does the instructor code work and mine doesn't?

Here's my code:

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setListeners()
    }
    private  fun setListeners(){
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text)
        for (item in clickableViews){
            item.setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
        }
    }
    fun makeColored(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {

            // Boxes using Color class colors for background
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

            // Boxes using Android color resources for background
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)

            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_one_text"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/box_one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_two_text"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_one_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_three_text"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_three"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_four_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box_two_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_four_text"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_four"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_five_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_three_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_five_text"
        style="@style/WhiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_five"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_four_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My system: Ubuntu 20.04 Android Studio 2021.1.1 Canary 11

Comment: they are probably using synthetic imports, which are outdated and deprecated at this point. just use findViewByID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is using **Kotlin synthetics imports**.

You need this import in you `MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and check that your `build.gradle` file (Module) has the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

However, the example you are following is probably outdated, it is currently recommended [Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variables before using them . You can either use databinding / viewbinding / findViewById for the same :

Do  the following :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   
   private lateinit var box_one_text : TextView
   private lateinit var box_two_text : TextView
   private lateinit var box_three_text : TextView
   private lateinit var box_four_text : TextView
   private lateinit var box_five_text : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        box_one_text = findViewById(R.id.box_one_text)
        box_two_text = findViewById(R.id.box_two_text)
        box_three_text = findViewById(R.id.box_three_text)
        box_four_text = findViewById(R.id.box_four_text)
        box_five_text = findViewById(R.id.box_five_text)
        setListeners()
    }
    private  fun setListeners(){
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text)
        for (item in clickableViews){
            item.setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
        }
    }
    fun makeColored(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {

            // Boxes using Color class colors for background
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

            // Boxes using Android color resources for background
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light)

            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a working method but it is not what is used in the example he is following.

Comment: I agree ,  but the question ask for solution to the answer. It never asked how to do the exact way , how it is done in the Video . Kotlin synthetics are deprecated , so recommending solution using them would not be right .